# What Icon should be used to show you can 'view' it?

Tags: icons

I'm building something for my work where you can view bookings.

So I have a list of different bookings that are click-able and I have an icon to show that it is 'viewable'.

[image]

When one of the elements is clicked a modal will show with all information about that  booking.

My question is, is the 'eye' icon the right icon to be using as I get a feeling it doesn't indicate you can view it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say this, but I think you might have chosen the wrong icon.

The 'eye' icon is usually used in circumstances where users are allowed a peek at the censored information. For example, you would see this while typing a password to unlock your computer.

Other application is some developers use this icon to represent that this item is for view only and no editing allowed.

Anyway, if the result of tapping on an element is to display information about that element, I suggest the 'i' icon, as displayed below.

[image: Info icon]